# How to Implement the help button with question mark icon on the WizardDialog

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have implemented a Wizard and WizardPage. I noticed that it has a help button with question mark icon. I would like to open a browser internal/external with a static url(www.stackoverflow.com). I have tried a few things but I couldn't find what gets executed when the button is clicked.

1. I have implemented the `HelpListener` on both WIZARD & WIZARDPAGE; but could not get the method to be invoked when I click on the button.

   public void helpRequested(HelpEvent e) {
   PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getBrowserSupport().getExternalBrowser().openURL(new URL("http://www.stackoverflow.com"));
   }
2. In the WIZARD constructor I have `setHelpAvailable(true);` and it gives me the Help button with the text.
3. I also tried the HandleEvent in the WIZARDPAGE with `SWT.Help` event type but again nothing happened.

I am not sure if & how I can add listener to this button? and How I could implement to open a browser by clicking on this button.

Please advice. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't believe, this is exactly what I wanted. I spent at least 3 hours  trying to resolve and could find the performHelp method that gets invoked when that button was clicked. Thank you so much! But yes it is a duplicate, pls let me know if i have to delete this question? I am not aware of the guideline.

Answer (score 0):

Each `org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardPage` can implement `performHelp()`, there you should be able to open a browser with your help.